# Why do my hover effect and image rise up and go down at different speeds?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have it so that when you hover over an image, the image and the opacity covering the image rise up. For some reason, when they do, they do not always rise and fall at the same speed. I can't figure out why. I would love if you guys could take a look and try to figure it out. I have a more complete version of my website here: https://jsfiddle.net/3L92f07m/  Take a look when you get a chance. Thanks

```js
let target = document.querySelector('.column img');
target.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => document.querySelector('.column p').style.opacity = '0');
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.bigproj {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.proj {
  padding-top: 42px;
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  font-weight: 900;
}

#clickimage {
  top: 220px;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
}
a.images{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
.none {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#abtproj {
  top: 300px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
}
.animate11 {
  -webkit-animation: animate11 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate11 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate11 {
  100% {
    top: 240px;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;

  }
}

@keyframes animate11 {
  100% {
    top: 240px;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
}

.column p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .6s ease-out;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 31px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.column:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  top: -7px;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  height: 100%;
}

.column img {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  transition: all .1s ease-out;
}

.column:hover img {
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  position: relative;
  top: -7px;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}

#totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 600px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  left: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  top: 585px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 430px;
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 385px;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column" id='column1'>
        <a class="images" href="#"></a>
        <img class='arcadeimg' src="../Images/arcade.jpeg" alt="Arcade" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head1'> Parapraph #1 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>Arcade Machine</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" id='column2'>
        <img src="../Images/car.png" alt="Car" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head2'> Parapraph #2 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
          t amet consectetur adipisicing
           elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
          luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>Electric Car</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" id='column3'>
        <img src="../Images/pinball.jpeg" alt="Pinball Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head3'> Parapraph #3 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>Pinball Machine</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" id='column4'>
        <img src="../Images/vending.jpeg" alt="Vending Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head4'> Parapraph #4 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>Vending Machine</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" id='column5'>
        <img src="../Images/sriraques.jpeg" alt="Sriracha Quesadillas" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head5'> Parapraph #5 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>Sriracha Quesadillas</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" id='column6'>
        <a class="images" href="#"></a>
        <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1000/0*kBHpKva09AsGj7RQ" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head6'>  web code </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>Website Development</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" id='column7'>
        <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/77/170477-050-1C747EE3/Laptop-computer.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head7'> Web Server </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>Web Server</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" id='column8'>
        <img src="https://nctennis.com/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=13&image_path=/images/2018/11/27/Wheelchair.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head8'> Adaptive Tennis </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>Adaptive Tennis</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <footer id='footer'>
      <p class='footwords'>
        © 2020 By Rom Fradkin. Proudly Individually Coded.
      </p>
    </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is this here:

```
.column img {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  transition: all .1s ease-out;
}
```

You need to change that to have the same transition time as your other animations. (Change it to .6s would match the hover transition time)

---

```js
let target = document.querySelector('.column img');
target.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => document.querySelector('.column p').style.opacity = '0');
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.bigproj {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.proj {
  padding-top: 42px;
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  font-weight: 900;
}

#clickimage {
  top: 220px;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
}
a.images{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
.none {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#abtproj {
  top: 300px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
}
.animate11 {
  -webkit-animation: animate11 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate11 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate11 {
  100% {
    top: 240px;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;

  }
}

@keyframes animate11 {
  100% {
    top: 240px;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
  }
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
}

.column p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .6s ease-out;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 31px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.column:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  top: -7px;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
  height: 100%;
}

.column img {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  transition: all .6s ease-out;
}

.column:hover img {
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  position: relative;
  top: -7px;
  transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}

#totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 600px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  left: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  top: 585px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 430px;
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 385px;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="column" id='column1'>
        <a class="images" href="#"></a>
        <img class='arcadeimg' src="../Images/arcade.jpeg" alt="Arcade" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head1'> Parapraph #1 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>Arcade Machine</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" id='column2'>
        <img src="../Images/car.png" alt="Car" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head2'> Parapraph #2 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
          t amet consectetur adipisicing
           elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
          luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>Electric Car</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" id='column3'>
        <img src="../Images/pinball.jpeg" alt="Pinball Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head3'> Parapraph #3 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>Pinball Machine</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" id='column4'>
        <img src="../Images/vending.jpeg" alt="Vending Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head4'> Parapraph #4 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>Vending Machine</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" id='column5'>
        <img src="../Images/sriraques.jpeg" alt="Sriracha Quesadillas" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head5'> Parapraph #5 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>Sriracha Quesadillas</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" id='column6'>
        <a class="images" href="#"></a>
        <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1000/0*kBHpKva09AsGj7RQ" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head6'>  web code </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>Website Development</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" id='column7'>
        <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/77/170477-050-1C747EE3/Laptop-computer.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head7'> Web Server </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>Web Server</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column" id='column8'>
        <img src="https://nctennis.com/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=13&image_path=/images/2018/11/27/Wheelchair.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head8'> Adaptive Tennis </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>Adaptive Tennis</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <footer id='footer'>
      <p class='footwords'>
        © 2020 By Rom Fradkin. Proudly Individually Coded.
      </p>
    </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In situations like that, I usually **remove all the elements that set transitions**.  I see that in your code it is separated.

Also, I think it is a good practice to create a **specific class** with my transitions settings. (my opinion)

For me, **it is easier to correct some little mistakes**.

Also, **be careful** with the regular **opacity**.

How does it sound to try that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try when transition is disable for ".column p" class like:

```
.column p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  //transition: all .6s ease-out; // <-- rise and falls the same speed.
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 31px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```